# ASP.NET MVC 2 RC Validation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use the validation capability of ASP.NET MVC 2 (RC)

I have a

**viewmodel**

```
public class CategoryPageViewModel
{

            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage="Category name required")]
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

**action**

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoryPageViewModel categoryModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Completed");
        }
        return View(categoryModel);

    }
```

**view**

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post)) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create new category</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="CategoryName">Category name:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("CategoryName") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CategoryName", "*")%>
        </p>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

On submit it says the id field is also required but I have not set the Required attribute.

What am I doing wrong or is it a bug? This is the RC release downloaded today 26/12/09.

Answer (score 3):

Your Create method is trying to construct a new `CategoryPageViewModel` from the posted form collection.

```
public ActionResult Create(CategoryPageViewModel categoryModel){...}
```

However, as your form only contains an input for `CategoryName`, your controller method cannot create a new `CategoryPageViewModel` where id is required.

You have two solutions to your problem:

1. Make the `Id` in `CategoryPageViewModel` nullable as @Andrew mentioned.

   ```
   public int? Id { get; set; }
   ```
2. **Recommended Solution:** Keep the Id as not nullable, but render this value in your form as a hidden input. This will allow you to keep your system Id intact from controller to view and back again.

   In the view add the `Id` as a hidden input using the following:

   ```
   <%= Html.Hidden("Id") %>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass in the Id, make it nullable ... i.e.:

```
public class CategoryPageViewModel
{
            public int? Id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage="Category name required")]
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

or don't include it at all.  How do you expect to perform any type of database update without an ID though?

Comment: Id will be auto generated by db. Id will be required only when editing a category or assigning a category to another related object.